# Weird CoreData Crash [NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _nilOutReservedCurrentEventSnapshot__]

Tags: objective-c, core-data

All of a sudden I am getting some weird CoreData crashes, has anyone seen this before or know what could be going on?

```
#   Binary Image Name   Address Symbol
0   RRio    0x003353b0  testflight_backtrace
1   RRio    0x00334bec  TFSignalHandler
2   libsystem_platform.dylib    0x3949f062  _sigtramp
3   CoreData    0x2e46446a  -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _nilOutReservedCurrentEventSnapshot__]
4   CoreData    0x2e45eee4  -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:]
5   CoreData    0x2e4584f0  _performRunLoopAction
6   CoreFoundation  0x2e6b11cc  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
7   CoreFoundation  0x2e6aeb70  __CFRunLoopDoObservers
8   CoreFoundation  0x2e6aeeb2  __CFRunLoopRun
9   CoreFoundation  0x2e619c26  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
10  CoreFoundation  0x2e619a0a  CFRunLoopRunInMode
11  GraphicsServices    0x3330d282  GSEventRunModal
12  UIKit   0x30ebd048  UIApplicationMain
13  RRio    0x000adcda  main in main.m on Line 15
14  libdyld.dylib   0x39384ab6  start
```

Compiling for iOS 6.1 minimum and using ARC

Comment: Enable Zombie Objects for diagnostics and you can see more details on your crash.
This settings is in "Product - Scheme - Edit scheme..." menu in Xcode. ![Enable Zombie](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0fETy.png)

Comment: It would help if you included information about how the app is set up, what's happening in the app when you get this error, basically any kind of detail that might help understand the situation.